# PHP> Sort query results by name while letting each letter be on the top sometimes

Tags: php

I'm currently working on a site that will display a list of online shops,
Each shop will be stored on my database and I'll be using PHP to select and display them.

But since those shops will pay me, I want to let each shop to be on the top of the list sometimes,
(for example if the shop name starts with a "Z", they will probably complain for being on the bottom of the list all the time, so I want to keep it fair).

So I thought about letting each letter be on the top of the list for an hour, but i have no idea how to do that..
Is that even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something else to keep in mind is even though you want to be "fair" to the shop openers, you also want to keep consistency on the site to your visitors. If your visitors have to keep searching for the link to a shop because it's constantly moving around, they're going to get frustrated and possibly not use your site. In my opinion, you need to find a way to be "fair" to the shop openers while keeping a consistent experience for your visitors.

Comment: you could perhaps have a priority field, where you can priortise your shops, not sure if this would be an ideal solution for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd show a separate box and call it "today's pick" or something with just one shop in it. That way you can push the shops starting with "Z" to the top once in a while and at the same time keep the user experience of a list of shops which is sorted normally.

Then use the database to save which shop has been in the "today's pick"-box how many times to get them all up there equally.

Answer (score 0):

There's no sane way (that I'm aware of) to handle this directly in SQL without adding a "priority" field to your schema (although it's possible, it would be convoluted at best). That said, here are two suggestions:

**Modify your schema**

Simply add a "priority" field to the relevant schema and sort by priority, name (or whatever the default is). You will of course need to reset the priority field every hour, but this is a fairly trivial task.

**Handle it in PHP**

1. Carry out the query as per usual.
2. Grab all the results into an array.
3. Re-prioritise as required based on the current hour. (You'll need to [array_splice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) the item(s) you want to bump out of the array and then [array_unshift](http://www.php.net/array_unshift) them to the top.)
4. Output based on the array.

This will of course become more convoluted/less efficient if you need to handle pagination, but the basic idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

A nice solution would be to add another column to the database with the shop names, and call it something like "last_shown" then when you show this shop, update the column with a timestamp, and each select do something like:

"SELECT name,link FROM shops ORDER BY last_shown DESC"

then in php you could check

```
<?php

if($row['last_shown']+3600 > now()){
    //run select but in ASC order
    //update the new row's column to the current timestamp

}



?>
```

that way it will only update once an hour, but otherwise it will keep selecting the shop at the top of the list for the hour

sorry it's a bit of a mess i just typed this out quickly at work

Answer (score 0):

You can add 
1) a extra column as shown_times in schema 
2)  `order by shown_times asc` 
3) & as a shop is shown you would +1

or

**Another solution :**
You can even use `ORDER BY RAND()`